# How do I set urlpatterns based on domain name or TLD, in Django?

Tags: django, session, request, django-urls

How do I set urlpatterns based on domain name or TLD, in Django?

For some links, Amazon shows url in native language based on its website tld.

[http://www.amazon.de/bücher-buch-literatur/](http://www.amazon.de/b%C3%BCcher-buch-literatur/)    ( de : books => bücher )

[http://www.amazon.fr/Nouveautés-paraître-Livres/](http://www.amazon.fr/Nouveaut%C3%A9s-para%C3%AEtre-Livres/)   ( fr : books => Livres )

[http://www.amazon.co.jp/和書-ユーズドブッ-英語学習/](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%92%8C%E6%9B%B8-%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%83%89%E3%83%96%E3%83%83-%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E5%AD%A6%E7%BF%92/)   ( jp : books => 和書 )

( the links are incomplete and just show as samples. )

Is it possible to get host name in urls.py? (request object is not available in urls.py) or maybe in process_request of middleware and use it in urls.py(how???)

Any alternate suggestions how to achive this?

```
#---------- pseudocode ---------- 

website_tld = get_host(request).split(".")[-1]

#.fr French  : Books : Livres
#.de German : Books : Bücher

if website_tld == "fr":
    lang_word = "Livres"
elif website_tld == "de":
    lang_word = "Bücher"
else:
    lang_word = "books"

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^%s/$' % lang_word,books_view, name="books"),
                       )
```

The url pattern needs to be built based on tld and later in the template, `<a href="{% url books %}" >{% trans "books" %}</a>` to render html as `<a href="Bücher">Bücher</a>` or `<a href="Livres">Livres</a>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<s>You have to do this at the webserver level (for example using mod_rewrite in Apache) or with middleware (for example [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1119/))</s>

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624827/in-a-django-web-application-how-do-you-give-users-their-own-subdomain)

---

Update: after your comment I thought about it some more.  I liked Carl Meyer's answer, but then realized it wouldn't handle {% url %} reversing properly.  So here's what I would do:

**Multiple sites:** You need to use the [Django sites framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/).  Which means making site instances for each language using the Django admin.

**Multiple settings:** Each language site will also have its own settings.py.  The only differences between each site will be the `SITE_ID` and `ROOT_URLCONF` settings so, to follow [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) principle, you should keep the common settings in a different file and import them into the master file like this:

```
# settings_fr.py
SITE_ID = 1
ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls_fr'
from settings_common import *

# settings_de.py
SITE_ID = 2
ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls_de'
from settings_common import *
```

... and so on.

**Multiple URL conf:** As implied above, a url conf for each site:

```
# urls_fr.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^Livres/$', books_view, name="books"),
)

# urls_de.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^Bücher/$', books_view, name="books"),
)
```

... and so on.

This way the url name (in this example "books") is the same for all languages, and therefore `{% url books %}` will reverse properly and the domain name will be the domain_name field of the Site object with `SITE_ID`.

**Multiple web server instances:** In order for each SITE to work properly they each need their own server instances.  For apache + mod_wsgi this means a different wsgi application for each SITE like this:

```
# site_fr.wsgi
import os, sys, django.core.handlers.wsgi
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings_fr'
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

... and so on along with matching apache virtual host for each site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mybooks.fr
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/site_fr.wsgi
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Hopefully this is clear :)

Comment: Thanks Van, Maybe I am missing the point from the other question you refer. Here, the url patterns needs to be built based on tld, and later in the template, <a href="{% url books %}" >{% trans "books" %}</a> to render html as <a href="Bücher">Bücher</a> or <a href="Livres">Livres</a>

Comment: Van, Thanks for such a detailed writeup!

Comment: @Van In some of the answers people suggested to use [django-subdomains](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for using multiple subdomains in a single django project.It looks that will simplify the things a bit.But from the docs I didn't get how to use it. Can you provide the solution using that.Which is better using django-subdomains or the way you described above ?

Answer (score 8):

You can probably do this with a middleware that retrieves the TLD via request.META['HTTP_HOST'] and prepends it to request.path; then your root URLconf can switch out to language-specific URLconfs based on the TLD as the first URL path segment.  Something like this (untested!):

```
class PrependTLDMiddleware:
""" Prepend the top level domain to the URL path so it can be switched on in 
a URLconf. """

def process_request(self, request):
    tld = request.META['HTTP_HOST'].split('.')[-1]
    request.path = "/%s%s" % (tld, request.path)
```

And in your URLconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^de/' include('de_urls')),
    url(r'^fr/', include('fr_urls')),
    url(r'^[^/]+/', include('en_urls'))
)
```

And then de_urls.py, fr_urls.py, and en_urls.py could each have all the URLs you need in the appropriate language.

Answer (score -1):

In django there's a table called "Sites". Maybe you can do something with that?