# How to make multilingual login in django?

Tags: django, authentication, multilingual

I need to create multilingual website. But there is a problem with the login address.
Do you know, how I can have /login/ for EN and /prihlasit/ for CS, etc... ?

I can specify just one login url in my settings.py

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill for you, but one way is to use multiple site instances (one per language) as detailed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676457/how-do-i-set-urlpatterns-based-on-domain-name-or-tld-in-django/676472#676472).

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here but can't `/prihlasit/` be a login form in Czech which POSTs to `/login/` when the user presses the submit button?