# Django Subdomain

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I'm trying to make a basic store app.  I've set up a database so that every product is tied to a particular store: let's call the stores Shoes, Toys, and Books..  I need to set up subdomains for the app (it's in the assignment specs, no choice there) so that I can map to shoes.myapp.com, toys.myapp.com and books.myapp.com.  What I *think* I need to do is somehow set up the subdomain (which I've googled but am confused about:  is [this the way to go?](http://thingsilearned.com/2009/01/05/using-subdomains-in-django/)) and then, I guess, filter my databases from the info in the subdomain so that only products that have the store name "Shoes" for example appear on the page.  Am I anywhere approaching the right track or is there a much better way to structure this?

Comment: what webserver are you running? You may want to use your webserver to translate the subdomain to an environment variable.

Comment: did your problem solve?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use this application: django-subdomains. http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

And then, in your settings.py, you should use:

```
SUBDOMAIN_URLCONF = {
    'toys': 'yourproject.urls.toys',
    'shoes': 'yourproject.urls.shoes'
(...)
}
```

If you need to use the name of the subdomain in a view, it will be attached to the request object:

```
def your_view(request):
    subdomain = request.subdomain
    products = Products.objects.filter(store=subdomain) #an example how to use it to specif database queries. I dont know how your models are
```

Comment: OK--this looks like what I want... a little confused though.  So, I think the second part with the request object makes sense to me, which is the important part.  I've read the docs and your example a couple times, though, and I'm still a little lost.  

My URLs follow this structure:
myproject.storename.pagename

The store names are toys, shoes, books.  The page names are 'products', 'checkout', and 'shoppingcart' along with / for the homepage (is that how you'd phrase that?).  So 12 pages altogether--four for each of three stores.  Do I need to map those all out individually?

Comment: That doesn't feel very Pythonic.  What am I missing?

Comment: If the behavior is the same for all your apps, you can map the stores all together AND DEAL with each subdomain like in my example view. 

I don't understand why this is not pythonic.

Comment: I meant what I said, not your answer.  I shouldn't have to write out 12 urls, right?  I'm very new here and not quite following your suggestion.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate the answer something like [Van Gale's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676457/how-do-i-set-urlpatterns-based-on-domain-name-or-tld-in-django) for the same thing without using the package

Comment: Please notice that django-subdomains cannot be used with Django 1.9 or upper versions. But maybe you can check https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts/