# How to run different Django apps on different subdomain

Tags: django, http, django-urls

Can it be possible to run Different Django apps on different Subdomains.
For Example:

For `api.mydomain.com` all request will be handled by my `API` app. But all other requests will be handled by my `core app`.
I just want my `API` app to handle request made on `api.mydomain.com`. And all other `requests` should simply be passed to `www.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Something like here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676457/how-do-i-set-urlpatterns-based-on-domain-name-or-tld-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `django-subdomains`.

`Subdomain helpers for the Django framework, including subdomain-based URL routing and reversing.`

Found solution at http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to your question, but if you are looking for providing an API to your website, [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is  recommended for doing it. With DRF you can can serve both regular webpages ([TemplateHTMLRenderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer)) and API responses ([JSONRenderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#jsonrenderer)) in the same URI depending on the request.

If you really need to have your API in a different subdomain then the advice of het.oosten can work for you.

Hope it helps.